# RPi 2 B No wireless interfaces found - eth0: Link is down

Tags: pi-2, wifi, setup

I tried to setup a new RPi 2 Model B using NOOBS. I followed the steps the  ["Getting started" guide.](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-getting-started/2).

At the "finishing the setup" step, Pi was not able to find any wifi connections to update the software so I chose skip. After the setup the wifi symbol appears with 2 X's. When I click on it I get `No wireless interfaces found` and when I hover over it I get `eth0:Link is down`.

I tried to change the Locale but nothing happened with the wifi. I set the country wifi to my country but this does not seems to save the change after reboot. It shows `no set`.

I don't have internet connection and command: `sudo apt-get update` gives only errors, and the command `sudo iwlit wlan0 scan` gives:

```
wlan0 Interface doesn't support scanning
```

I have setup another RPi in the past (RP3 model B, in a different place and network) but without such problems. Any idea of what might be the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Pi2B does not have onboard wifi. Are you sure you have 2B and not a 3B(+)? Or do you use a USB wifi dongle? In that case, you need to update your question with relevant info such as make and model, the output of `lsusb` and `ifconfig`.

Comment: My board is Pi2B but I assumed that, like Pi3B is going to recognize wifi networks without ethernet cable or a wifi USB adapter. Are these two the only way to connect to internet a Pi2B?

Comment: These two are the 'standard' methods. There are alternatives (ESP modules, 3G/4G mobile chips, etc) but I would only consider them for 'non-standard' situations.

Comment: Thank you @Dirk. This is probably my problem. Sorry for the silly question. I should have checked the specs first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi2B does not have onboard wifi, just wired Ethernet.

In order to get wireless network access, you have to use a different device, for example a Wifi USB dongle.